# is it possible for a kingdom to live off of rice, beans, eggs, potatoes, and chicken, and general food from foraging and hunting?

Tags: internal-consistency, civilization, food, kingdom

my question is literally right there. the general amount of people is about 2500 people. 1000 are men, 1000 are women, and 500 are kids. whatever farm area amount is required, I won't mind. as long as it isn't absolutely ridiculous. the era is generally in the medieval era. I just need to know if a diet of egg, chicken, rice, beans, and potatoes is livable or not. or maybe there is an online tool I could use to see if this is possible? any other information you need/request I will go ahead and add in. people have been mentioning that rice and potatoes weren't in the medieval era together, or at least weren't grown in the medieval era together, and i am here to mention that while the "kingdom"(people have also mentioned this is more of a county than a kingdom) is generally based off medieval, this is also a completely fantasy world.

the other part is the fact that potatoes and rice can't be grown together due to different conditions, and to that, i would like to ask: can a 20 degrees fahrenheit lower half of the year and 20 degrees fahrenheit higher half of a year, where the half way mark is 60, (so its about 80 degrees at its highest, and 40 degrees at its lowest) be suitable to grow potatoes during the warmer season, and rice during the colder season? it never gets below freezing but it does get cooler during the "void moons" one of the two ingame seasons.

the other bit of requested info was the landscape due to me mentioning the foraging and gathering. i've imagined this place as being a very open plain with shrubs and the occasional tree, due to deforesting for housing, and supplies, and space for farm land, before reaching an immediate forest about 10 miles out. in the lower sections of the plains is just wetlands and in the higher areas is dryland. so i guess we could add fish to the diet. about animals, i'd say there are just hare's, and a few types of canine in the forest, and deer, and general pesky fantasy monsters we don't need to worry about, cause they're made of magic.

Comment: isnt that basically what medieval people eat ? assuming you mean general medieval times, south american farming potato already, since you mention rice. because potato is not farmed yet in europe, before renaissance or colonialism start.

Comment: That's one very very small kingdom... Maybe a tiny little county, at best. (And there was no place in the Middle Ages where they had both rice and potatoes. Rice comes from Asia, potatoes come from the Americas. The two crops never met until after the Middle Ages.)

Comment: what kind of beans?

Comment: @Alexp  well technically spain has rice during  8th century brough by arab

Comment: @LiJun: Rice arrived in south-eastern Europe during the Antiquity, probably via Egypt, or maybe after Alexander's conquest of the Persian empire. In Spain, rice was introduced by the Arabs during the Middle Ages. But for potatoes they had to wait much longer. (In most things agricultural Eurasia is one integrated continent.)

Comment: @AlexP yeah just recently recheck again it exist in medieval era i get mix up wih the risotto invention which happen during renaissance and spread to england

Comment: well france grow potato and rice though, at least after potato was introduced and rice start to spread from spain, as i mention they also spread to england, it may not during medieval but it happen during colonialism era, the brittish love their curry so maybe check what rice they use, also as i mention what you describe is basically what medieval people eat, so i dont understand what your question is, since they do live off from that diet. as i mention medieval is not just mean exclusively europe but it just timeline unless you specifically mean culture.

Comment: @LiJun well i'm glad that this question is way simpler than i assumed it'd be. also ooooh curry sounds good. i should think of things we could make out of the general resources. rice cakes, and all. although that requires sea weed i think.

Comment: i dont know much about cooking or their ingredient, so i am not sure they use sea weed or not, beside europe also has eat seaweed too at least for the people live in the shore iam not sure is it compatible or not either, but i can imagine europe make mochi variant or this type of [rice cake](https://www.healthline.com/nutrition/are-rice-cakes-healthy) though if they figure it out, or you mean nori maki mochi ? thats the only rice cake i found from google that use seaweed.

Comment: @AlexP  How many Tuatha kingdoms were there in medieval Ireland, and what was the average population of one of them?  If the population of Ireland was 1,000,000 at one time and there were between 50 and 200 kingdoms in Ireland at that time, the average kingdom would have had a population of 5,000 to 20,000.  persons, 2 to 8 times the figure of 2,500 requested for the fictional kingdom.

Comment: Kingdom with 2.5k people? The early middle ages had cities with easily *ten times* that population. And that wasn't even unusual. The advance of the middle ages generally saw populations rise, so this kingdom is extremely small.

Comment: I would advice you read Marvin Harris "Cows, pigs, war and witches". Potatoes, pigs and wars. Just what you need. IRL check.

Comment: does the amount of people really matter @VLAZ? again, i did mention it in the edit that this is more of a county. it does have a "castle" but it's more of a town hall. i'd say that this place is more of a medieval town?

Comment: @michaelgriffin Your numbers seem incorrect for medieval times 1000 men & 1000 women to 500 kids does not seem correct. In medieval times, 50% of the kids did not live to see the third birthday, so there had to be much more of them. So I would assume 1000 men, 1000 women and about 5000 kids.

Comment: honestly though, this is a town, and not a kingdom. as i'm sure i've stated before? @JulianEgner

Comment: For context: According to this: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/23733/what-was-the-average-size-of-french-families-during-the-middle-ages, the average household in the medieval era ranged from 4.4-8.5.  So for 2000 adults there should be 2400-6500 children.  You would typically see lower ratios in cities and higher ratios in agricultural communities; so...  Julian Egner's ballpark of 5000 is actually a really good estimate for a place like this.

Comment: ok then. i will raise the population to about 7000+

Comment: A better question is this diet realistic, I know of no agricultural civilization that did not cultivate some fruit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your culture can survive on these staples, however for what we call complete nutrition today, you would do well to add a leafy green, a root vegetable other than the potato, a cultivated berry (for a more reliable and plentiful supply than foraging), an ungulate like a goat, camel, or cow, and some fish or shellfish.

Your listed foods are going to cover the macronutrients (major sources of calories; carbs, protein and fat) with no problem. Most historical cultures only had one staple carbohydrate source, so to have two makes you that much more protected from famine. The anachronism and cultural difficulties of cultivating rice and potatoes have been covered by other answers, suffice to say, consider wheat instead of rice or yams instead of potatoes.

There are 13 essential vitamins, of which you're only going to have trouble with three. The egg yolks are going to provide you with most of these vitamins, while grains will round out the majority of B-complex vitamins, and you'll get a vitamin here or there across the rest of your listed foods.

Vitamin B9 (folic acid) and Vitamin K are normally produced in ample amounts by the human body, but a little extra of either never hurt, especially for pregnant women and young children. However, the only listed food they'll be found in are the livers of your chickens; one or maybe two chickens will feed quite a large family, but the livers would only be big enough to give each family member a small bite, requiring you to prioritize. Consider a leafy green like a lettuce variety, arugula, mustard greens, spinach or cabbage, depending on average daytime temperature. All of these contain both of these vitamins in abundance and don't require killing too many of your egg-layers just for liver.

That liver is also your best listed source of Vitamin A, though egg yolks have quite a bit of both Vitamin A and of "carotenoid" precursors that can be converted into the vitamin. A red to orange root vegetable like carrots, beets or yams have good carotenoid content, as does the spinach already mentioned, and various gourd-family fruits like zucchini, butternut squash and pumpkin.

The third is Vitamin C, which is found in most species of edible berry, including currants, blackberries, raspberries and blueberries among others, all of which are native to most of the northern hemisphere. Consider cultivating these for a more plentiful supply; as native vines and bushes, they're not hard to grow where you want them, don't require much attention, and can thrive in rockier areas of your farmland that aren't suitable for other crops, or as hedgerows between farmed plots.

There are 16 essential minerals in modern nutrition, most of which you are going to have no trouble with between the chicken and the beans. One major one you're going to miss with what you have is soluble calcium. The most common source today is in milk, and you have no milk producer in your list. Legumes and leafy greens give you a little calcium, but it's a mineral that vegetarians and especially vegans historically struggled with until soybean products became more widespread in Western agriculture and cuisine. A herd of goats don't take much room, can eat a variety of vegetable matter including grass, and produce a milk very rich in calcium and other vitamins and minerals. In addition to the milk, bone meal, made simply by drying and grinding the bones and gizzards of the animals you slaughter for meat, has historically been an important source of calcium, both dietary and as fertilizer (which gets calcium into your crops and thus into your diet).

Also keep in mind that the goats (and other mammals) have to give birth regularly to keep lactating, and that only female goats are really useful for this purpose beyond a couple of rams to keep the female goats pregnant. So, much like your chickens, farmers artificially keep a very female-heavy population by culling the males for meat, giving you a second good protein source (and a red meat like mutton is more nutrient-dense than chicken). The goat skins are also a key source of leather, which is critical to medieval technology above and beyond your nutritional needs. Sheep are another good option especially in colder weather, as you not only get milk, meat, skins etc but also wool (there are hairier breeds of goat, but mohair is a relative niche fiber compared to wool).

Another key mineral source you may struggle with in a more inland area is salt, which provides the key electrolyte ions sodium and chlorine. This is normally trivial to get in abundance for any culture with access to the ocean, since all you have to do is boil clean seawater dry and presto, sea salt. However, it can be more of a challenge to get sufficient salt intake in more inland areas. The saltier the soil, the less fertile it is, and while there are salt mines dating back to 5000 BC, these aren't nice places to work for a variety of reasons (historically they were mined by slaves or prisoners with *extremely* short life expectancies) and aren't found everywhere humanity has settled, so a landlocked haven for a medieval European farming culture is going to produce ample but very low-sodium produce, and will have to trade for its salt. The East Asian answer is soybeans, but these didn't spread out of Asia as a food crop until the late 1700s, and most of their sodium content as a foodstuff comes from boiling them in seawater to extract and neutralize their trypsin inhibitors; boiling anything else in that much salt is going to put plenty of it in the food. You can get enough of these electrolytes with a meat-rich diet, or by drinking a sparing amount of animal blood (blood plasma is by definition an isotonic solution of electrolytes, but human digestive systems don't process whole blood very well), but if chicken is your only animal protein it will be a bit harder to manage. The easiest and least gory answer all around is to make sure you give your fictional community good access to a body of salt water.

The last one you *could* have some trouble with is iodine. Essential for proper thyroid function, in turn regulating growth and metabolism, you can get enough of it as long as the soil you grow your staples and vegetables in is iodine-rich. Geographical regions to avoid on Earth include sub-Saharan Africa and heavily mountainous regions; almost anywhere else on the planet, especially in coastal wetlands, you'll get sufficient iodine from vegetables and grains grown in the local soil, but fish or shellfish like mussels would be an ideal addition to your group's diet for a little extra.

Comment: suggesting from the plethora of information given by you, and others, this does give me an idea of having a sea side town that imports to the kingdom things like salts and sea food. i guess i could definitely grow berries in-town, and have goats around for milk and food. btw why can't we just drink human milk? sheep is another good idea to maybe have. moving on, i definitely do think that we could have farms for growing things like lettuce and mustard greens.

Comment: also this isn't me negating things you said with "oh i already thought of it!" because honestly you provided these ideas, and i'm just stating what i'm accepting from it for the general feel of the town. you are really good at this honestly. never even thought about milk, and your sheep idea made me think about clothing, and i never thought that we could just grow berries.. i may be stupid,

Comment: @michaelgriffin you can also use soy sauce to replace salt in landlock region if they have soy though thats how landlock china get substitute for salt cant use for food preservation as far as i know, or roman fish sauce Garum but it require salt fish though, since your world is not exactly europe anyway, also the peasant eat pork, and generally either salt meat or dried meat including fish, but one thing that definitely break the immersion is spice since most of spice grow in hot climate or tropical, maybe sugar cane as far as i know it manage to grow in southern spain. also cheese and yogurt.

Comment: @michaelgriffin i wonder what you originally think medieval people eat ? especially medieval europe ? since at least milk and milk product like cheese is well known to be europe stereotype dish outside of bread. although as far as i know, berries is indeed forage rather than farmed during that time, outside of strawberry which not considered as berry. and for why they dont use human milk as far as i know due to cow or other pasture animal produce more milk to support more people, and you can get human disease if the person have unknown disease.

Comment: @michaelgriffin i mean landlock regions in china

Comment: @michaelgriffin oh yeah also cow and such eat grass or wheat straw which human cant eat and considered abundant, also you need them to be pregnant to get milk first. so if it done to human, not only you will require more food just to get more milk, you also get more human to feed each time you need to reproduce milk unless you gene engineer the woman, which kinda disturbing and they may protest against such inhuman act, while if you dumb them down like most domestic animal it may also dumbing down your future generation, unless you create some caste system i guess, basically to much chore.

Comment: ah. that is interesting, and i guess i understand now. @LiJun

Comment: well, I never really thought about what people in the medieval times ate until I asked this question, and provided what I assumed to be what medieval people ate. honestly, you guys have opened up a bijillion of different foods that would be added. also, I wonder why you guys assumed i meant Europe.  this place is a fantasy place, it could grow any number of different things, as long as it can handle a generally stable climate, never freezing and never burning hot. although I guess if I wanted that, I would have just asked about that. but then I wouldn't have learned so much.

Comment: @michaelgriffin Mother's milk requires mothers. That requires your community to keep their women pregnant pretty much from puberty to menopause, which would make each female in your society the mother of about 30 children, the eldest of which would only be about 12-15 years younger and popping out grandbabies. There's no faster ticket to an exponential growth curve, assuming even half of these children lived to childbearing age themselves, easily outstripping the carrying capacity of the arable land within a few generations (less than a century at this rate).

Comment: Dairy farmers managing a herd of cattle, sheep, goats etc face the same problem; each of their cattle have to calf every couple of years at least, and that will cause the herd to outgrow his pastures' carrying capacity. Even if the land is there, managing the herd becomes impractical in a number of other ways. To keep the herd at a steady size, the farmer will send most males and older females to the slaughterhouse, keeping only young cows. Translating that back to humans turns the underlying framing of your community's food needs into a horror story all its own.

Comment: @michaelgriffin at first i already assume that you mean general medieval times rather than the medieval europe culture when i read the food with rice and potato which is not common for europe, as i mention in my first comment technically south america kingdom or empire like maya, inca, aztec, etc already farming potato, but since majority of people when read medieval they usually think it mean as medieval europe centric, basically due to the heavily linked to the fall of rome and the christian religion in europe which is the reason of this medieval time/period or europe change of culture.

Comment: @michaelgriffin  so next time i suggest maybe use fantasy medieval instead so they wont get confused with real medieval europe or the general medieval period. oh yeah also i forgot to mention medieval europe also has sausage and product from animal blood too like blood pudding.

Comment: blood pudding ew.. also yeah that would be a horror story all in it's own right. @KeithS

Comment: and thanks @LiJun. next time i will definitely state fantasy medieval.

Comment: Bone meal is high in calcium and was used as a dietary supplement for a very long time. So you can scratch calcium off the list.

Comment: @Hippeus_Lancer - Still is used for livestock and in fertilizer. Solubility is a problem; powdering it improves that solubility slightly by simple surface area, but calcium compounds in milk are designed by nature to be easily absorbed. Lead poisoning due to contamination of the meal or the animal's feed is also a potential issue in certain locales/time periods (though strangely enough, lead toxicity in bone-based calcium supplements gained peak notoriety in the 70s at the height of leaded gasoline use).

Comment: There is another good reason for introducing some milk production (like cattle or goats): cheese! If your kingdom experience winters then it needs some source of food that doesn't spoil easily to last those months. And cheese has historically been one of those foods.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, but there are some issues

For one thing, potatoes did not appear in Afro-Eurasia until after the Middle Ages, with the Columbian Exchange. When potatoes were introduced to Northern Europe it led to a population boom that may have contributed to the Industrial Revolution. Potatoes are far more efficient in terms of calories per acre than any old world crop.

Beans are very nutritious, and chickens provide extremely valuable protein.

Rice feeds billions for a reason. It stores very well and is a good source of carbs. But the issue with growing rice and potatoes is that they usually don’t grow in the same conditions. Rice needs a lot of water and doesn’t like the cold. Potatoes on the other hand don’t do as well in very wet and hot places. But this is not insurmountable, as with the right strains of rice and the right strain of potatoes alongside field management you would be able to have plenty of both.

You also really don’t have that many people at all, it’s absolutely tiny for a kingdom.

The hunting and foraging is extremely dependent on the environment. If it’s a rich temperate or subtropical forest with plenty of water access than they would be absolutely golden. If it’s the Sahara or Siberian tundra things would be harder

Comment: well, the thing is that this place isn't earth, its just fantasy, and i'm just reffering to potato-like and rice-like crops, which is what you guys seem to have a problem with. i should probably mention that. and i should talk about the landscape as well, that would be a good idea. and also the hot and cold system.

Comment: @Michaelgriffin Yes, you should mention landscape and climate, they are of paramount importance when it comes to agriculture and general survival. May I suggest having sweet potatoes or yams in place of normal potatoes if you want it to be hot and humid?

Comment: its not really hot and humid, i edited it. it is  more of a cool climated area,  that at it's peak gets to 80+ degrees.

Comment: @Michaelgriffin Ok, in that case you’ve actually got very reasonable conditions for growing rice and potatoes

Comment: yesss my place actually works!

Comment: also thank you cause you actually made me ask things i've never asked before, related to the what the place is actually like.

Comment: @Michaelgriffin Glad to be of assistance

Comment: I'm not a dietitian, but don't they need at least SOME fruits and other, not-so-carb-heavy, vegetables to provide key nutrients? I'm thinking of things like scurvy, etc.

Comment: well there are forests a couple miles out, and plenty of shrubs which i assume that some will be berry bushes. i'd assume that the kingdom gets import and export as well from other kingdoms, and i'm sure that they could do apple trees as well @CaM

Answer (score 4):

Technically a person can survive well into adulthood without any major health issues off of just eggs and potatoes; though, cholesterol may become an issue when older. I addressed this in a bit more detail in this previous question: [How long can humans survive on this diet?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/115836/how-long-can-humans-survive-on-this-diet/148977#148977)

If you are adding on top of this general hunting and foraging then your people will definately be fine. Since people will instinctively seek out any nutrients they may be lacking when looking for food; so, if you've missed something, there is a good chance you will get enough of it to remain healthy in the things you forage for.

Frankly, what you've described is actually a very idealized situation for a medieval settlement.  The population is big enough to discourage raiders, but small enough to maintain good sanitation without modern plumbing. You have nearby access to wetlands, highlands, and forests; so, you have a great diversity of natural resources at your disposal.  These people will probably be a lot more well off than your average medieval folks.

**Two issues I see though:**

1: The region is probably too wet and temperate to support potatoes.  I've tried growing potatoes in a climate similar to what you are describing, and if the random heat wave doesn't kill them, temperate zone fungi  will.  Sweet potatoes however are much more suited to the tropical and temperate zones; so, if your swap potatoes for sweet potatoes, you'll add a lot of plausibility to your setup.

2: This is a likely size for a fiefdom, but not a kingdom.  Settlements that size would have been large enough to ward off the standard Viking raid, but they would not have been large enough to maintain their independence.  In the medieval feudal system, this place is probably governed by a well-to-do knight, sheriff, or lesser lord who would have "king like authority" over the people, but would himself be subservient to higher ranking lords.

Comment: Cholesterol issues has little to do with consumed cholesterol. Majority of cholesterol is produced by your own body. In your eggs and potatoes diet the potatoes would probably be more likely reason for cholesterol issues (as being overweight DOES contribute to high cholesterol)

Comment: @Negdo The issue is actually your Omega-3/Omega-6 balance.  Yes, your body can produce Omega-6 from anything, but the Omega-3 which your body uses to break down and manipulate Omega-6 must come from food; so, you either need to be cautious not to over-consume Omega-6 or include enough Omega-3 rich foods; so, by adding a good source of Omega-3 like fish or unprocessed grains, the cholesterol issue should be avoidable.